# Problems Installing 3rd party python modules in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, module

I am having trouble installing/utilizing 3rd party python modules such as pdfplumber or PyPDF2 onto VSCode.

When importing the library the output says : Import error: No module named pdfplumber

My initial steps into the file are as follows:

-created file

-initialized + activated venv through VSCode terminal

-pip install pdfplumber

-import pdfplumber through file

Additional info:
Built in libraries such as sys, requests provide a small description when you hover your mouse over the script within your code.
Yet with 3rd party modules like pdfplumber shows => 'pdfplumber: pdfplumber'

More additional info => edit:

I want to run python 3. VSCode selected interpreter says I am running python 3. My pyvengv.cfg says I am running 3.9.

Yet when running => print(sys.version) and print(sys.path) => say that I am running paths in python2 and running python version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

After activating the virtual environment, I use `pip install pdfplumber` to install the module.

Run `pip show pdfplumber` in integrated Terminal to check if it's installed in current selected interpreter.

Import it without errors:

[image]

Comment: VSC switches interpreters automatically doesnt it ? The interpreter and locations match when I have checked.

Comment: @Drew. Nope, you can manually select the interpreter and it won't change automatically unless the environment has something wrong. Create a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments) and try again.